# How to offset the effective location of a wall sconce?

Tags: electrical, bathroom-fixtures

A relative asking for help - didn't notice earlier that the construction crew located the right hand wall sconce really close to a corner:

[image]

Ideally, the location would vertically center of the lower outlet - that is, 4" or so to the left of its current location.

I had two ideas:

- put a pancake box in the desired location, run a wire to the existing box on the right. However, that leaves the original box and would require some cover. So could work but not ideal.
- design and build two shallow rectangular wooden bezels. The left would center over the existing box, and the right would offset the necessary inches as needed. Painting the two the wall color would help to blend them into the wall.
- buy a low-voltage assembly where you have a bar that lights can slide on. The two mounts wouldn't properly centers but lamps sliding on the bar could be exactly centered.

This is the best I can come up with now. I googled looking for "offset bezels" and such but never found anything.

Any and all ideas welcome!

EDIT: one or two studs located between the right box and desired location.

Comment: Are the sconce and outlet boxes in the same stud bay? That may make it relatively easy to add a new box for the sconce in the desired location and patch the drywall after removing the existing box. It's a matter of whether you can swing the existing wiring to the new location or need to extend it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're looking for a hacky solution. _Move the box_. Now's the time.

Comment: Tyco makes a Romex splice kit that can be buried in the wall per NEC rules if you can't quite reach the other location: [NON-METALLIC CABLE SPLICE & TAP CONNECTORS](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data+Sheet%7FEPP-3384%7F1904%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_EPP-3384_1904.pdf%7FA22899-000). It just has to be _rework_. ;-)

Comment: @HABO updated question to add this info - not in same stud bay

Comment: @isherwood due to extenuating circumstances allowing time for redo won’t work

Comment: I don't see how it'll be more work that what you've proposed.

Comment: Either you move it or you don't. carve a hole or use the exist6ing box hole and a right-angle drill to put a hole through the stud...

Comment: @HABO your idea of rework with splices is excellent! Definitely a viable option. Make it an answer will upvote and select it if they go for it.

Comment: @SolarMike can’t say for sure, but very likely not enough slop in the wires to relocate the box to the other side of the stud(s). Unfortunately I’m 2000 miles away from the site so no way to poke around. Rewire would involve at least removing most of the Sheetrock with no guarantee of success.

Comment: Where did the plans say the lights were supposed to be located? Was it just left up to the crew to put stuff wherever they wanted? This sounds sloppy, but not clear who is responsible for it being sloppy.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I had volunteered early on to review plans, that offer was not accepted. If I had to guess, they were shown on the left and right side of a vanity but not truly spec'd in terms of exact position.\

Comment: I believe the tyco splice kits are usually code compliant if and only if they can be fished back out. Do the trades have progress pictures of the job? They might show that the wire is fed straight across from the left, in which case it would be really easy to put in a new junction box.

Comment: It looks like there are multiple cables in that hole but a inwall splice will be the cleanest for exterior appearance at this point, once the walls are up changes use old work boxes all the time. If the cables are two short to re route to the other side of the stud and put a new box in use the splices. I have done similar as a pro it is a good suggestion and @HABO you should add this as an answer I would upvote it , op get ready for some sticker shock the tyco splices are spendy but to get the clean finish look if the cables are not long enough it’s the code compliant way to go.